# incremental drawing

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I'm trying to incrementally draw a waveform on a canvas in a separate thread, i.e. in each loop of the thread draw only the portion recently acquired by the hardware without redrawing the whole curve.

I am not sure if I can rely on the canvas' contents retained between `SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost` and `SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas`.

The documentation seems to be a bit ambiguous on that and my experiments give surprising results: the "old" contents is different for the canvas returned in two subsequent loops of the drawing thread. It looks as if two canvases were used alternately (but I checked - it is the same canvas but with different contents).

The simplest way which I found to reproduce this behaviour:

1. Import the LunarLander sample applicaton.
2. In the LunarView.run method insert sleep(500) instruction in the loop.
3. In the LunarView.doDraw method comment out the line:
   `canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);`, which erases the old contents.

Run the game and let the ship crash. You will see the intermediate positions of the ship but they will blink: odd and even positions will be shown alternately.

So, my question is: can we draw pictures adding changes only to the contents which has been drawn before and if so - is there any documented way of dealing with the strange behaviour described above?

Comment: use two bitmaps. One with background, and one with moving content

Comment: @Doomsknight. Thank you for the comment, however the problem is not in drawing the background, but in the fact, that some parts of the curve drawn in previous loops are visible every second loop of the drawing thread. Of course if I don't find answer to my question I will use a cache bitmap, but I need to reduce the drawing time as much as possible.

Comment: Based on the Lunar landing, when I used this as a base, I had the same problem. it was essentially flicking back and forth between two drawn images. Read the code carefully and think through what it is doing. It is most likely a bug in the origional code.

Comment: @ Doomsknight - the code seems OK. The flickering looks for me like some caching issue.

Comment: The lunar landing does not cache. It draws the background image each time (refreshing) and then draws the spaceship. Try this instead: http://blorb.tumblr.com/post/236799414/simple-java-android-game-loop

Answer (score 0):

The lunar landing does not cache. 
It draws the background image each time (refreshing) and then draws the spaceship.

```
private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // Draw the background image. Operations on the Canvas accumulate
            // so this is like clearing the screen.
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
```

Check your If clauses closesly. Maybe one is alternating true and false. This would cause things to draw and then not draw, in rapid succession.

Use Log if need be to output your booleans, to see if one is changing.

Failing this, this the following gaming loop instead.

http://blorb.tumblr.com/post/236799414/simple-java-android-game-loop